# Cambiar cantidad de unidades en un array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando una programación, donde tengo un selector de colores y por cada color al que se le hace clic crea un nuevo input de cantidad. Conforme voy añadiendo colores al array se me ve tal cual:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
  0:cantidad: "100"
    color: "Verde Fluor"
    color_id: 14
  1:cantidad: "100"
    color: "Morado"
    color_id: 24
  ....
```

Entonces cuando cambio un valor de los distintos inputs de cantidad "dependiendo cantidad de colores elegidos" necesito captura ese valor y de que color esta cambiando la cantidad. Entonces cuando cambio el input llamo a la función `cambia_cantidad` donde me traigo el valor y el color_id = id.

```
function cambia_cantidad(event) {
    var valor = event.target.value;
    var id = event.srcElement.attributes.id.value;
}
```

Pero estoy intentando remplazar ese valor una vez encontrado pero no lo consigo, estoy probando así:

```
colores_elegidos.find(v => v.color_id === id).cantidad = valor;
```

Entiendo que mi programación será un tanto peculiar, pero es la primera vez que estoy haciendo esto y a base de pruebas he llegado aquí.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto:

```
event.srcElement.attributes.id.value
```

Te retorna un `string`y `color_id` es un Number, y tu haces una *igualdad estricta* en

```
colores_elegidos.find(v => v.color_id === id).cantidad = valor;
```

La solución es:

1.- Usar igualdad débil `==`

```
colores_elegidos.find(v => v.color_id == id).cantidad = valor;
```

2.- Convertir alguno de los elementos

```
colores_elegidos.find(v => String(v.color_id) === id).cantidad = valor;
colores_elegidos.find(v => v.color_id === Number(id)).cantidad = valor;
```